# How to determine the Google Drive file associated with a Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an html document that references a Google-Apps-Script in its body element thusly:

```
<script src="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbytu7Jtninl6kBDcPU7OEwWEPDg-C9407OpQOVbh9v4NdtjUfQ/exec?prefix=callback&fname=doug"></script>
```

(At least I think that's what the above snippit does.)  When I load the page, the script runs properly as I would expect.  The problem is that I can't locate the script on Google Drive anywhere.  How can I determine what Google Drive file is associated with this script?  Thanks for any input.

```
   ... doug
```

Comment: Are you the owner of the script? You could recursively scan for all script files in your drive and go through them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a folder with it's sharing set to 'public on the web'. Any files within that folder can be accessed with:

https://googledrive.com/host/FOLDER_ID/FILENAME.JS

Hope that helps

Comment: I'm not sure that's exactly true.  If I create a folder on Google Drive with it's sharing set to 'public on the web' and then within that folder I create a Google Apps Script, I believe that the URL for accessing that script will not conform to the format you have given.  (It will look more like the src url in my original question.) My problem is that I have the URL for accessing the Google Apps Script.  I just need to know how to tell from that information what is the location of the associated Google Apps Script on Google Drive.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were trying to reference a file

Comment: Yeah.  I think that my use of the word, "file" in my original question was probably a poor choice of words.  Perhaps it would have been better if I had used a word like, "resource".  Anyway, thanks again for the input.

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing a search for all script files and look through them.
Try this out:

```
function myFunction() {
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles("mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.script'");
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    Logger.log(file.getName() + " - " + file.getUrl());
  }
}
```

Or do a search directly in drive https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/#search?q=app%3A%22Google%20Apps%20Script%22

Comment: Great idea.  Strange results.  The search only found one script.  It's my contactUs script.  That's all I've been able to find as well.  Roughly speaking, on Google Drive I only have about 100 files spread through about a dozen directories.  So, it's not real hard to do a manual search.  I'd say that the script doesn't exist but for the fact that it runs when I load the page.  I have no idea where that script is hiding.  I guess that's a bit of a problem with these Google formulated URLs. One can't tell from them by inspection where the script is physical located.  Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

I FOUND THE MISSING GOOGLE APPS SCRIPT and you won't believe where it was. It was in my Google Drive trash. Apparently I had previously deleted it.

So, the big revelation from all of this is that apparently deleting a GAS (and thereby relegating it to the Google Drive trash) does not disable the Google-provided link to that script.  I'm wondering if perhaps the Google-provided link might point to a physical portion of some disk drive somewhere rather than a file or directory on that drive.  Can someone please enlighten me on what's going on here?  I would really like to understand this.  Thanks.

```
  ... doug
```